# Vimeo oEmbed API stopped working

Tags: vimeo, oembed

We were using Vimeo oEmbed API, suddenly it stopped working. While checking API documentation at following link, its totally different now.

https://developer.vimeo.com/apis/oembed

Is there a way to find out when did API got changed, I am not able to locate last update date for Vimeo oEmbed API.

Comment: The only changes that have been made in quite some time, are we now encourage HTTPS. HTTP is still viable, yet not recommended. If you provide more details about the request you were making, the response you are receiving, and the response you expected we would be able to debug your issue further.

Comment: We were using following as request url, but now, (.json) needs to be removed from the end, its giving 404. Request URL ---https://vimeo.com/api/oembed.xml?url=https%3A//vimeo.com/76979871.json

Comment: .json was never valid at the end of the vimeo.com url. If it was allowed at any point it was a bug. If you want a json response you have to replace the ".xml" part of your url with ".json", so the proper url is https://vimeo.com/api/oembed.json?url=https%3A//vimeo.com/76979871